# pointIndex Unable to retrieve item from vector in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

Getting the following compilation error in Visual Studio '12

```
error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::at': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::at' to create a pointer to member line 39
```

**CODE**

```
Vector2dVector mVertices;

/// other code

for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.size(); pointIndex++) {
    mVertices.push_back(Vector2d(pointIndex * 2.0f, pointIndex * 3.0f ));
}

int size = mVertices.size();
CCPoint *pointArr = new CCPoint[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Vector2d vec2 = mVertices.at[i];  //Line 39 
    //pointArr[i].x = vec2->GetX();
    //pointArr[i].y = vec2->GetY();
}
```

Comment: Ok, it was a silly question I agree. I expected Visual Studio 2012's intelisense to warn me for this.

Comment: I think this is not a "silly question": everyone of us was a beginner once! :) Enjoy learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a typo here:

```
Vector2d vec2 = mVertices.at[i];  //Line 39 
                            ^ ^
```

You should use `()` with `std::vector::at` method call, instead of `[]`:

```
Vector2d vec2 = mVertices.at(i);  //Line 39
```

An alternative can be to use `std::vector::operator[]` overload (instead of `at()`):

```
Vector2d vec2 = mVertices[i];
```

The difference is that `std::vector::at()` does **bounds checking** on vector index, and throws an exception `std::out_of_range` if the index is out of range (preventing buffer overruns).

Instead, if you use `std::vector::operator[]`, bounds checking is disabled.

In other words, using `std::vector::operator[]` you have *faster* code, but you don't have run-time checks on vector indexes (so you must pay attention to your indexes, to avoid dangerous buffer overruns).

(To be more precise, in Visual Studio, if [`_SECURE_SCL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is set to `1`, there are bounds checking also for `std::vector::operator[]`).

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector2d vec2 = mVertices.at(i);
                         // ^ ^
```

You need parentheses, not brackets. `at` is a member function.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector2dVector::at` is most likely to be a function rather than a field of type array:

```
    Vector2d vec2 = mVertices.at(i);  //Line 39
```